# DIV element not changing height with content in responsive theme

Tags: html, css, magento

I have a Responsive theme that used to work but at some point has stopped working and im not sure why. When the screen width hits less that 780px the catalog grid page div just loses its height and the page becomes unscrollable .
this can be seen here http://tinyurl.com/nn2urkl
I was wondering if anyone could see why this is happening?

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rule that defines the height of your container in the file `grid_1170.css` (about line 1181).
Just comment out or delete the line

```
height: 200px;
```

and you'll be fine.

See my screenshot.

[image]